# Subscribing to Redux - React props issue

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I need to implement this function that checks the Redux variable in interval, say 5 seconds. My issue is that this variable is the content of a large, editable text; so subscribing to it normally causes app lags (because every typed letter is a variable's change).

Does anyone have an idea how to overcome it? I can post some code if you want, I just thought it's rather a theoretical problem..

Maybe I can render this component just every 5 seconds to avoid it being connected constantly?

Comment: Is the issue that the redux store is updating too often for a specific component subscribed to a specific state slice? I.E. when the state updates and triggers the component to rerender (because props updated) you want to "drop" a few of these "updates"? If possible, it may be better for the component where the data is being entered to throttle/debounce its dispatched actions to update state. React component rendering is rather asynchronous, any time state/props update triggers a rerender.

Comment: Is the issue really the text size? Try with a small text. Also, try to debug the render performance (google for "Profiling Components with the Chrome Performance Tab"). I would say that even updating a large text on every added character is not *necessarily* slow, so try to pinpoint the bottleneck.